# What differences does `__init__` make to a directory?

Tags: python, package, init

In python, a directory containing one or more modules sometimes has `__init__.py`, so that the directory can be treated as a python `package`, is this correct? What differences the `__init__` makes? (also another Q, is a python module just a python code-file with related and possibly independent (to other files) set of classes, functions and variables?)

Comment: You should read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition, the contents of `__init__.py` becomes the contents of the package when treated as a module, i.e. the contents of `somepackage/__init__.py` will be found in `dir(somepackage)` when you `import somepackage`.

Modules themselves can be Python code, [specially-crafted C code](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c), or they could be [an artificial construct](http://docs.python.org/c-api/module.html#PyModule_New) injected by the executable that loads the Python VM.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an [explanation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for why `__init__.py` is needed:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

As I've just recommended to another poster, the [tutorial on modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) is pretty informative.